# Why is my Qt5 QPixmap not showing correctly frames processed with some OpenCV algorithms?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, qt5

Thank you in advance for your support.

I am using OpenCV for processing video frames taken by a video camara, and showing the processed frames in a simple GUI implemented in Qt5. In the GUI, the images are shown using QPixmap in a label. The OpenCV algorithms should be right, since if I write the outputs are right, and they are basically some examples provided by OpenCV.

I have implemented different processings: For a conversion from color to grey scale, and for binary threshold (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtXu0.png)) the results are fine (this "view" of the camera is right). Nevertheless, when trying to display ("in real time") Keypoints detections (using SURF -see image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ1UL.png)-) and contours detections (using Canny -see image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dywc.png)-), the images displayed are strange.

The main problem is they seem to be at the same time "much closer" (see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ1UL.png)) and double (see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dywc.png)).

In the Qt code I am using:

```
ui->labelView->setScaledContents(true);
```

I do the conversion from the processed OpenCV frame to QImage using:

```
QImage output((const unsigned char*) _frameProcessed.data, _frameProcessed.cols, _frameProcessed.rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
```

And I display the image using:

```
ui->labelView->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(frame));
```

The GUI and the OpenCV processing are running in different threads: I move the image processing to a thread in an initial setup.

If you needed further information please just let me know.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,

[image: Binary Threshold image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: some opencv functions create their own output images. Are you sure the format ist what you expect?

Comment: I will try to check carefully the output formats and the transformation between OpenCV Images and QPixmap, and I will give feedback. That is one of my hypotheses, but I do not know exactly where the error could be.
My other idea is that somehow it had something to do with the time of processing of those algorithms and the multithreading, since this happens with the more time consuming algorithms...

Comment: can you try to create some reduced test code to test without asynchronous behaviour (not using the two diffrent threads)?

Comment: Finally I found a solution. As you pointed out, it had to do with the images formats. It was easily solved using this handy header: https://github.com/asmaloney/asmOpenCV/blob/master/asmOpenCV.h
which contains a set of functions for transforming betweem Cv and Qt Image formats. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2):

As [@Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) pointed out, it had to do with the formats of the images. I found [this handy code](https://github.com/asmaloney/asmOpenCV/blob/master/asmOpenCV.h) providing functions for an automatic transformation between OpenCv and Qt formats.